# The stroke order for the component 辶 (Chuo)

Tags: stroke-order

https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=zhe

If you click on the character zhe here, you will get an option to figure out what the stroke order is.  For some reason this zhe follows a different stroke order than the number/order of strokes of other characters that contain this component.

Is this the website's mistake, or is this an exception to the stroke order rule?  Are there other characters that take that many strokes to complete their chuo component part?

Comment: The radical 辶 come from 辵

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you talk about the method of writing 辶?

The difference is caused by the typeface or font.

明体

[image]

楷书

[image]

Comment: I understand Chinese Majority Taiwan, Japan, Korea, and ??

Comment: I don't understand what is below the writing style of 楷书.  So is either way to write correct?  Because on the website it is written in 4 stroke of radical, it is not just the way it looks.  Click to the MDBG website, click on and enlarge the Zhe character, and click the paintbrush.  It will 8 strokes total, 4 for the wen looking part of zhe and 4 for radical part.  Is this the website's error???

Comment: never mind I was wrong..lol

Comment: 1. Ancient prints sometimes have a few slightly different glyphs in the same word, the one selected as the standard font today is called the new glyph (新字形), and the others are called the old glyphs (旧字形).
Both new and old glyphs may have been used for hundreds of or thousands of years.
2. The standard strokes are based on 楷体.
You can take a look the strokes of 遮, which is in the same page you gave.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the website.

The following picture showes the "辶"(Simplified Chinese) in different fonts and characters.
[image: 辶]

Accually although the "辶" sometimes looks different and a little bit strange, it is always same and there's no exception. It's assembled by three parts (as the second line in the picture) and you can follwing the third line in the picture, which is its stroke order, to write.

---

> "Are there other characters that take that many strokes to complete their chuo radical part?"

Did you mean this? [Click here](http://www.hanzizidian.com/bs.html).

An online Chinese dictionary that sorted by the number of radical strokes.Click on a radical part and it will tell you which character has that.

Comment: On the website, if you click and show how to write zhe, which I do not think you did, since you are commenting this way..it takes 4 strokes to finish the left hand radical, not 3

Comment: sorry, i was mistaken..I incorrectly saw how they wrote = =